# radiobutton set checked if

Tags: android

I implemented a radiobuttongroup in the notepadv3 Tutorial.
I want to set a radiobutton checked if the string output is "Fehltag" or "Verspaetung".
it' not the complete source code.

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbtnVerspaetung"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/rbtnVerspätung" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbtnFehltag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/rbtnFehltag" />
</RadioGroup>
```

java:

```
    private RadioButton rbtnFehltag;
    private RadioButton rbtnVerspaetung;
    private void populateFields() {

    if (mRowId != null) {
        Cursor note = mDbHelper.fetchNote(mRowId);
        startManagingCursor(note);
        mTitleText.setText(note.getString(
                note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE)));
        mBodyText.setText(note.getString(
                note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_BODY)));
        mFehlzeitText.setText(note.getString(
                note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_Time)));
        mTest.setText(note.getString(
                note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_Test)));

        String ausgabe;
        //returns Verspaetung or Fehltag
        ausgabe = note.getString(note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_Test));

        rbtnFehltag.setChecked(ausgabe == "Verspaetung"); //it doesn't work
        //rbtnFehltag.setChecked(true); //this is working but it doesn't peform the task

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand what you are asking. But I think you're problem lies in the fact that you cannot use the == operator on Strings. I believe the == operator will compare Strings location in memory, rather than the content of the String. I think if you replace the tail end of your code with this:

```
String ausgabe;
//returns    Fehltag     or     Verspaetung
ausgabe = note.getString(note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_Test));
rbtnFehltag = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rbtnFehltag);
rbtnVerspaetung = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rbtnVerspaetung);
rbtnFehltag.setChecked(ausgabe.equals("Fehltag")); 
rbtnVerspaetung.setChecked(ausgabe.equals("Verspaetung"));
```

Strings are actually objects in Java. In general, you should only use the == operator when comparing primitives. == will compare the memory address of objects. This is useful when you need to know about identity rather than equality. But I dont think that is what you are going for here.

good luck.

Comment: i'm a newbie in java... i think in c# you can make it so (string == "abc")... thanks for the fast answer

Comment: no problem. I remember spending a few hours mucking around with the == operator and Strings when I was learning Java. Just remember that you have two options equals-equals and dot-equals. use equals-equals for primitives and for testing identity with objects. use dot-equals when testing for equality with objects. This almost always means that you will have to implement 'public boolean equals(Object obj);' That way you can define exactly what counts as "equal" for whatever object you are working with. Of course Strings are a special case where dot-equals is already implemented in thr right way

Comment: note that all objects will ultimately inherit from the Object class. I believe Object implements .equals. however i think that it compares memory address by default which is almost certainly not what you want.